# Docker openapi client generator can't find "spec file"

Tags: docker, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I have generated a openapi json file, and I wish to create a typescript client using docker.
I have tried to do something similar to what is on the openapi generator site (https://openapi-generator.tech/ - scroll down to docker part), but it doesn't work.

Command from site:

```
docker run --rm \
    -v $PWD:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i /local/petstore.yaml \
    -g go \
    -o /local/out/go
```

What I have tried:

```
docker run --rm -v  \
    $PWD:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i ./openapi.json \ 
    -g typescript-axios
```

No matter what I do, there is always a problem with the ./openapi.json file. The error which occours:

```
[error] The spec file is not found: ./openapi.json
[error] Check the path of the OpenAPI spec and try again.
```

I have tried the things below:

```
-i ~/compass_backend/openapi.json
-i openapi.json
-i ./openapi.json
-i $PWD:/openapi.json
cat openapi.json | docker run .... (error, -i is required)
```

I am out of ideas. The error is always the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've published a video tutorial to show how to use openapi generator with docker on Windows. Hope it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MuEP01h1XU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by switching from bash to powershell. Docker uses windows path notation and I was trying to use bash notation. If you type pwd in bash you get this:

```
/c/Users/aniemirka/compass_backend
```

And if you type pwd in powershell you get this:

```
C:\Users\aniemirka\compass_backend
```

So docker was trying to mount a volume to /c/Users/aniemirka/compass_backend\local, and it couldn't read it because it is not windows notation, so the volume didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using bash using the following command:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local alpine sh -c "apk add --no-cache openjdk11 && wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/5.3.0/openapi-generator-cli-5.3.0.jar -O /opt/openapi-generator-cli.jar && java -jar /opt/openapi-generator-cli.jar generate -i /local/api.yaml -g go-server -o /local/api/gen"
```